# About fragment life cycle

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle

I have something weird in my fragment, when the activity is restarted or paused, fragments are not responding to my **onClick** events and this is my code , what should i do to not face this problem again
hint this is a sign up fragment that returns an model object to the activity throw **communicator**, i hove any one can help me

````
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.gahez.gahez.Constants;
import com.gahez.gahez.Definer;
import com.gahez.gahez.R;
import com.gahez.gahez.activities.UserSignUpActivity;
import com.gahez.gahez.data_wrappers.Courier;
import com.gahez.gahez.fragments.interfaces.SignUpCommunicator;
import com.gahez.gahez.utilities.Utilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {


    private ImageView profilePicImageView;
    private ImageView showPasswordIMageView;
    private EditText passwordEditText;
    private EditText emailEditText;
    private EditText userNameEditText;
    private EditText phoneEditText;
    private EditText confirmPasswordEditText;
    private EditText nationalIdEditText;
    private Button signUpButton;
    private TextView addImageTextView;
    private CheckBox maleCheckBox;
    private CheckBox femaleCheckBox;
    private ConstraintLayout backgroundConstraintLayout;

    public Activity context;
    private Intent outComingIntent;
    private SignUpCommunicator communicator;

    private File userPhotoFile;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_fragment,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setContext();
            setCommunicator();
            defineViews();
            setListeners();
            Definer.setupUI(backgroundConstraintLayout,context);

    }


    //my methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setListeners(){
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        maleCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        femaleCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        profilePicImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void defineViews() {
        profilePicImageView =  context.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        showPasswordIMageView =  context.findViewById(R.id.password_show);
        passwordEditText =context.findViewById(R.id.password);
        signUpButton=context.findViewById(R.id.next);
        emailEditText= context.findViewById(R.id.email);
        userNameEditText= context.findViewById(R.id.username);
        phoneEditText= context.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        confirmPasswordEditText= context.findViewById(R.id.conferim_password);
        backgroundConstraintLayout=context.findViewById(R.id.background_constraint_layout);
        addImageTextView = context.findViewById(R.id.add_image_text);
        maleCheckBox=context.findViewById(R.id.male_check_box);
        femaleCheckBox=context.findViewById(R.id.female_check_box);
        nationalIdEditText= context.findViewById(R.id.national_id_edit_text);
    }

    public void setContext(){
        context=getActivity();
    }

    public void setCommunicator(){
        this.communicator =(SignUpCommunicator) getActivity();
    }

    public Courier getCourier(){
        Courier courier = null;
        String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        String confirmationPassword = confirmPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
        String phoneNumber = phoneEditText.getText().toString();
        String userName = userNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String nationalId = nationalIdEditText.getText().toString();
        String gender = getGender();
        if(!email.equals("")&&!password.equals("")&&!confirmationPassword.equals("")&&
           !phoneNumber.equals("")&&!userName.equals("")&&!gender.equals("")&&!nationalId.equals(""))
            courier = new Courier("carrier",userName,email,password,phoneNumber,
                    gender,nationalId);
        return courier;  //it returns null if any field is empty
    }

    public String getGender() {
        String gender="male";
        if(femaleCheckBox.isChecked())
            gender="female";
        return gender;
    }

    public String validatePasswords(){
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        String confirmationPassword = confirmPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
        if(password.equals(confirmationPassword)){
            if(password.length()>=8)
                return Constants.VALID_PASSWORD;
            else
                return Constants.SHORT_PASSWORD;
        }else
            return Constants.NOT_MATCHING_PASSWORDS;
    }

    public boolean isValidDataEntry(Courier courier){
        if(courier==null) { //if courier is null then the fun getCourier find one or more field empty
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.complete_your_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }else {
            if(!Definer.validateEmailAddress(emailEditText.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.invaild_email_address), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                String passwordValidationResult = validatePasswords();
                if(passwordValidationResult.equals(Constants.SHORT_PASSWORD)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.password_must_be_eight_chars_at_least)
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(passwordValidationResult.equals(Constants.NOT_MATCHING_PASSWORDS)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            getString(R.string.passwords_are_not_matching),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;

            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkStoragePermissions(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(Constants.STORAGE_PERMISSIONS,Constants.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,"hello");
            return false;
        }else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void getImageFromDevice() {
        if(checkStoragePermissions()) {
            outComingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            outComingIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(outComingIntent, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    //override methods
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.next:
                Courier courier = getCourier();
                if(isValidDataEntry(courier))
                    communicator.onSignUpDataConfirmed(courier);
                break;
            case R.id.profile_pic:
                    getImageFromDevice();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==context.RESULT_OK){
            if(data!=null){
                if(requestCode==Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap profileImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                        this.userPhotoFile = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(imageUri,context));
                        profilePicImageView.setImageBitmap(Utilities.resizeBigImages(profileImage));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Constants.STORAGE_PERMISSIONS[0])) {
                        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "noo");

                        Utilities.showBasicAlertDialog(
                                context,
                                R.drawable.ic_baseline_warning_24,
                                getString(R.string.permission_alert),
                                getString(R.string.go_to_settings_grant_the_storage_permissions_to_use_this_feature),
                                getString(R.string.ok),
                                null,
                                (dialog, which) -> {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                },
                                null
                        );
                    }
                    else
                        Utilities.showBasicAlertDialog(
                                context,
                                R.drawable.ic_baseline_warning_24,
                                getString(R.string.permission_alert),
                                getString(R.string.you_need_to_grant_storage_permissions),
                                getString(R.string.yes),
                                getString(R.string.not_now),
                                (dialog, which) -> {
                                    getImageFromDevice();
                                },
                                (dialog, which) -> {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                        );
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.male_check_box:
                if(isChecked)
                    femaleCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                break;
            case R.id.female_check_box:
                if(isChecked)
                    maleCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing where you call `defineViews();` and `setListeners();`

`onCreateView()` is the ideal place to do this since it is a method used by the Fragment itself and not by the activity lifecycle.

Whereas `onActivityCreated()` is only called when the fragment is created or reattached but not when it is restarted.